# SQL query not returning all days from timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to run an sql query grouping each data by date. My column in named `created` and is a timestamp. The query works fine using `YEAR(created), MONTH(created), WEEK(created)` and shows all the results, however, with day it shows only a range. How can I solve this?

query with YEAR or MONTH or WEEK(created)

```
SELECT created
FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
GROUP BY YEAR(created)    //<-- that can be either YEAR, MONTH or WEEK
```

This query returns all data divided into year, months or weeks between 3rd of March 2017 and today

query with DAY(created)

```
SELECT created
FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
GROUP BY DAY(created)
```

This query, however, returns all data divided days only between 3rd of March 2017 and 31st of March

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use `DATE(created)` instead of `DAY(created)`. Because `Day()` returns the day of the month (1-31) not the date.